Problemas con Require_once en Plugin
Estoy creando un plugin y he creado una clase cRegistro.php que quiero enlazar. La estructura va así.
demo
|-- admin
      |--cRegistro.php
|--demo.php

Estoy usando la siguiente línea en demo.php
namespace nsRegistroTC;

// Exit if accessed directly.
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

require_once plugin_dir_path(__FILE__).'admin/cRegistro.php';

Pero me retorna error. Qué podría mejorar?
Saludos.

Mencionas que hay un error, pero no indicas cuál es y, como puedes comprender, esta información es vital para poder entender cuál es el problema y probablemente sea el punto de partida para que un experto en tema pueda ayudarte a resolver la situación en que te encuentras. De otra forma, se hace muy difícil responderte. Encontrarás más información en [ask] y [mcve]. Un saludo.

Como indica @jachguate en su comentario, pulsa en [edit] y agrega cuál es el mensaje de error. Si el problema es que no está encontrando el archivo, empieza por depurar la ruta con un var_dump(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__)); verificando si esa salida, combinada con admin/cRegistro.php es o no la ruta correcta del archivo.

Gracias por contestar. El problema está en esta línea.
require_once plugin_dir_path( FILE ).'admin/cRegistro.php'
Me sale error 500.

El error 500 indica que ese script tiene problemas de PHP (puede ser de código erróneo o de permisos durante su ejecución) y como no vemos que contiene poco más te podremos decir.  Intenta debugearlo cortando su ejecución en distintos puntos hasta que encuentres lo que lo hace saltar.

La mejor forma de depurar los errores 500, y todos los errores, es revisando el log de errores. Te recomiendo que aprendas a revisar ese archivo, te vas a ahorrar muuuchas horas en el desarrollo. Para más detalles revisa esta pregunta.

Pon un simpe "Hello World" en cRegistro.php y mira si se enlaza a demo.php
